# Determine the number of records in a salesforce table without knowing the table's field names

Tags: rest, salesforce, soql

I'm using the Salesforce REST API to determine the number of records in each Salesforce table. Ideally, I would be able to a query like this on each table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <variable_table_name>

                  --or--

SELECT COUNT() FROM <variable_table_name>
```

Unfortunately, SOQL does not support `*` as select all. Running `COUNT()` without a field doesn't work either. How can we determine how many rows each table contains without knowing the name of at least one field?

My last resort is a two step process:

1. Use the SObject Describe resource to retrieve a field name
2. use `COUNT` with that field name

That means two network calls for each table rather than just one. I'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure why count() isn't working for you.
Salesforce dev docs says it should work. I don't have an instance to test on right now. [link](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_count.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to use `COUNT()` without any fields. Thank you Salman Syed. The problem for me was that the web response for `COUNT(Id)` differs from the web response for `COUNT()`.

`COUNT(Id)` WebResponse Content

```
{
    "totalSize":1,
    "done":true,
    "records":[{
         "attributes":{"type":"AggregateResult"},
         "expr0":260
    }]
}
```

`COUNT()` WebResponse Content

```
{
    "totalSize":260,
    "done":true,
    "records":[]
}
```

When using `COUNT()`, I needed to look at `totalSize` property rather than the `records.expr0` one.